# Ubuntu internet connected but not working

Tags: network-manager, lan

I have working internet, and it’s is not available when I use the browser! The ping to google.com gives me the ip but 100% pocket loss. This works fine when I switch to Windows on dual boot.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Edit:
ifconfig gives: enp7s0 (Ethernet), lo, tun0 and wpl6s0

Comment: Is this wireless or wired? Could you please post the output of `ifconfig` and `ethtool -i ethX` and finally `ethtool ethX` where ethX is the name of the interface that is supposed to be working. Do that and we should be able to solve it from there.

Comment: @jwcooper thanks for your response! Unfortunately ethtool is not installed on the system. I have both wireless and wired, neither of them works.

Comment: *Update*: the `tun0` caused the issue, I ran `sudo ip link set tun0 down` to remove it and everything worked just fine. Also tun0 was caused because of openvpn installation.

Comment: That openVPN install would have been pretty helpful to know about before. Regardless, glad you got it fixed.

Comment: @jwcooper I appreciate your help! Thanks